# JQuery Dialog load data with loading effect in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to show a popup window using JQuery dialog. I have loaded the dialog with my action like,

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 520,
                height: 'auto',
                title: 'Edit Zip Code',
                position: 'center',
                show: { effect: 'fade', duration: 800 },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load("/GridAjax/CreateAlbumPartial?id=" + guid);
                },
                close: clear,
                buttons: {
                    "Update": function () {
                     ....
}
});
```

Now my view is loaded little bit slower. so that at first look it shows previous view. so i decided to put some loading effect untill data loaded. I have tried like showing loading image in open of dialog and hiding the loading image on success like,

```
open: function(){
$('#loadingDiv').show();
}
.
.
.
success: function(){
$('#loadingDiv').hide();
}
```

but that doesnt work for me and it doesnt settled in a proper position. so please guide me to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead :

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    //exisiting stuff
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/GridAjax/CreateAlbumPartial?id=" + guid,
            success:function(data){
                $(this).html(data);
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#loadingDiv').show();
            },
            complete:function(){
                $('#loadingDiv').hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: I have a update button when i click on that i have did ajax call. now i want to display loading untill update opertion gets completed. I have followed above way but doesnt works for me. guide me.

Comment: @user999689, the code will be same on update. Are you using ajax to do the update things just like above?